# Sequelize obtain associated model data in the property

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've two models, `User` and `Category`

User model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT(19),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    defaultScope: {
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['password']
      }
    },
    scopes: {
      withPassword: {
        attributes: {}
      }
    }
  })

  User.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    let values = Object.assign({}, this.get())
    delete values.password
    return values
  }

  return User
}
```

Category model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT(19),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false
    },
    created_by: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT(19),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'categories',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  })

  Category.associate = (models) => {
    Category.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'created_by'
    })
  }

  return Category
}
```

My query to find the category:

```
const category = await Category.findOne({
  include: [{
    model: User,
    required: true,
    attributes: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email']
  }],
  where: {
    id: req.params.id
  },
  limit: 1
})
```

When I execute the query, the response I expected was,

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "License",
    "created_by": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Magesh",
        "lastname": "Kumaar",
        "email": "mk@test.com"
    },
    "created_at": "2018-09-03T07:41:29.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-03T07:41:29.000Z"
}
```

But the response I obtained was,

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "License",
    "created_by": 1, // I expected the user information here
    "created_at": "2018-09-03T07:41:29.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-03T07:41:29.000Z",
    "User": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Magesh",
        "lastname": "Kumaar",
        "email": "mk@test.com"
    }
}
```

The user information is available at both `created_by` as Id and another `User` property that contains other information

I tried the `as` option, but it didn't seem to work. Is there any way to get the user information in the `created_by` key itself.

Answer (score 3):

Need use aliases.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Example:

index.js

```
require('dotenv').load();

const { User, Category } = require('./models');
const sequelize = require('./database');

(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
await Category.associate({ User });

await User.create({
    firstname: 'firstname',
    lastname: 'lastname',
    email: 'email@email.email',
    password: 'password',
});

await Category.create({
    name: 'name',
    created_by: '1',
});

const category = await Category.findOne({
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: {
        model: User,
        required: true,
        as: 'created',
        attributes: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email']
    },
    where: {
        id: 1,
    },
});

console.log(category.toJSON());
})();
```

Category Model file:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT(19),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
        allowNull: false
    },
    created_by: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT(19),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id'
        }
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'categories',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
});

Category.associate = (models) => {
    Category.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'created_by',
        as: 'created',
    })
};

return Category;
};
```

result:

```
{ id: 1,
  created: 
   { id: 1,
     firstname: 'firstname',
     lastname: 'lastname',
     email: 'email@email.email' } }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer. But you've mentioned an alias `created` instead writing the response in `created_by` is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Alas, but no. Because of this, used names of entities.
example:
{ id: 1,
  user: 
   { id: 1,
     firstname: 'firstname',
     lastname: 'lastname',
     email: 'email@email.email' } }

Comment: Did you like my answer? If so, rate it.